# Compilation error when attempting to call methods which define a variable from another class

Tags: java, static

These two classes are described in depth in the javdocs but in short: it is meant to calculate the CO2 emissions from electricity use. However I am returning an error when attempting to compile that reads as follows:

> non-static method `calcAverageBill`(`java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>`) cannot be referenced from a static context.

I'm not certain what the issue is, could anybody help?

```
public class CO2fromElectricity
{
    private double monthBillAverage;                           
    private double monthPriceAverage;                          
    private double annualCO2emission;                         
    private double emissionFactor;                             
    private double months;                                    

    CO2fromElectricity() { }

    public double calcAverageBill(ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill)
    {
        monthBillAverage = 0;
        for(double billToken : monthlyBill)
        {
            monthBillAverage += billToken;
        }
        return monthBillAverage / monthlyBill.size();
    }


    public double calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice)
    {
        monthPriceAverage = 0;
        for(double billToken : monthlyPrice)
        {
            monthPriceAverage += billToken;
        }
        return monthPriceAverage / monthlyPrice.size();
    }


    public double calcElectricityCO2(double avgBill, double avgPrice)
    {
        emissionFactor = 1.37;
        months = 12;
        return annualCO2emission = avgBill / avgPrice * emissionFactor * months;
    }
}


public class CO2fromElectricityTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill = new ArrayList<Double>();                                                
        ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();                                               
        double averageMonthlyBill,                                                                               
               averageMonthlyPrice,                                                                             
               annualCO2emission;                                                                               
        double monthlyBillToken1[] = {192.14, 210.42, 231.25, 186.13},                                           
               monthlyPriceToken1[] = {.07, .06, .08, .06};                                                      

        for(int index = 0; index < monthlyBillToken1.length; index++)                                            
        {
            monthlyBill.add(monthlyBillToken1[index]);                                                           
            monthlyPrice.add(monthlyPriceToken1[index]);                                                        
        }

        ArrayList<CO2FootprintV1> electricCO2outputput = new ArrayList<CO2FootprintV1>();


        averageMonthlyBill = CO2fromElectricity.calcAverageBill(monthlyBill);                                    
        averageMonthlyPrice = CO2fromElectricity.calcAveragePrice(monthlyPrice);                                 
        annualCO2emission = CO2fromElectricity.calcElectricityCO2(averageMonthlyBill, averageMonthlyPrice);      


        System.out.println("Average Monthly Electricity Bill: " + averageMonthlyBill);                           
        System.out.println("Average Monthly Electricity Prince: " + averageMonthlyPrice);                        
        System.out.println("Annual CO2 Emissions from Electricity Useage: " + annualCO2emission + "pounds");     
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind for future questions that we don't need all these comments at all. And for your own improvement: you don't need many of your inline comments. Stuff like `//Main method` is pointless.

Comment: Part of a class. It's not that I desire it within the code--it's that the course I'm taking does. You're not insinuating that I should go back through my code and edit out all the required comments before I post it?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I insinuate. It's not relevant to the problem so it shouldn't be in there.

Comment: It's insanely stupid that you believe I'm going to go back and edit all of the comments out of my code because you don't like them personally. I've never had complaints, and they're not an issue--they don't inhibit function, and I don't see what your issue is with them.

Comment: This isn't just my opinion: they're the guidelines. Questions should describe the specific problem and not clutter the post with things that don't matter. The amount of comments in your post made it hard to have an overview. If you wish to debate this (I can always be wrong), you can do so on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `calcAverageBill` is a method that operates on objects of type `CO2fromElectricity`, but you're calling it as if it were a static method. That is, you must call it on an instance of `CO2fromElectricity`, e.g.:

```
CO2fromElectricity inst = new CO2fromElectricity();
averageMonthlyBill = inst.calcAverageBill(monthlyBill);
```

Alternatively, you can make your methods static by adding the static keyword to your method definitions:

```
public static double calcAverageBill(ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill)
```

Taking a quick look at `CO2fromElectricity` you probably want the fields you've defined (such as `monthBillAverage` to be local variables within each method rather than as fields or static properties, because your class doesn't benefit from defining these in the scope of an instance or in the scope of all executions (in fact, you might run into some trouble the way they're currently defined).